# spark python convert RDD tuple with nested tuples into sigle tuple

Tags: python, apache-spark, tuples, pyspark, rdd

I have my final RDD and it looks like:

```
(44, (136.38, 2))
(2, (108.53, 3))
(4, (24.13, 1))
(35, (65.89, 1))
```

I'd like to have it in form:

```
(44, 136.38, 2)
(2, 108.53, 3)
(4, 24.13, 1)
(35, 65.89, 1)
```

Please note that this is an spark RDD, created out of two other RDDs:

```
combined = reduced_total.join(reduced_count)
```

I could accomplish the task with :

```
combined = combined.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1][0],x[1][1]))
```

but it does seems very pythonic. Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack:

```
combined.map(lambda x: (x[0], *x[1]))  # Python 3
```

or concat:

```
# this creates a single element tuple and uses __add__ method on it.
combined.map(lambda x: (x[0], ) + x[1])
```